# How to fix Photoshop CS3 startup error "One or more files in the Adobe Application Support folder" after upgrading to 10.6?

Tags: snow-leopard, adobe-photoshop

After upgrading to 10.6 (Snow Leopard) Adobe Photoshop gives an error message on every start of the application:

> "One or more files in the Adobe Application Support folder, necessary
>   for running Photoshop, are missing. Please run the Phtoshop installer
>   and re-install Photoshop."

How to fix this Photoshop CS3 on every launch error "One or more files in the Adobe Application Support folder" message that start occurring after upgrading to 10.6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax` isn’t loading. It’s possible the file is actually missing, but it’s more likely that you’ve upgraded to Snow Leopard.

Snow Leopard requires 64-bit versions of every plug-in, including OSAXes. [The versions of Adobe Unit Types that shipped with CS3 and CS4 are 32-bit](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/unit-type-conversion-error-applescript.html).

To fix this:

1. [Download the 64-bit version of Adobe Unit Types](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/516/cpsid_51615/attachments/Adobe_Unit_Types.osax.zip).
2. Delete the old `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types` file (when it's there).
3. Drag the downloaded `Adobe Unit Types.osax` file to your `/Library/ScriptingAdditions/` folder.
4. Launch Photoshop.

sources:

- http://paulschreiber.com/blog/2010/11/02/howto-fix-photoshops-missing-application-support-files-error/
- http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/unit-type-conversion-error-applescript.html

Comment: This worked for me. I was copying my working version of photoshop CS3 from one mac to another instead of upgrading my OS because my original backup failed.

Comment: I know this is an old topic, but thank you, gracias, kiitos. This worked perfect. My elderly iMac/SL box is acting up so I ported Adobe to my less elderly ash can pro running Mojave. This solution worked for my rig.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me before when I reinstalled Leopard and upgraded to Snow Leopard 10.6. When I tried to double-click or drag and drop to Photoshop the files wouldn't open. I looked in the *Library* folder and there was no *ScriptingAdditions* folder.

So, I went to my Time Machine backup folders (on my external drive) and chose a backup folder  from 3 days ago. Opened *Library* and found *ScriptingAdditions* folder, which contained the Adobe Types Unit file. Dragged the ScriptingAdditions folder to my desktop and then put it in the upper level Library of my hard drive. Works every time.

Comment: Did you mean reinstall Leopard and upgrade to SL? Because reinstall SL and upgrade to SL doesn't make much sense.